# Compile-time trigonometry in C

Tags: c, optimization

I currently have code that looks like

```
while (very_long_loop) {
    ...
    y1 = getSomeValue();
    ...
    x1 = y1*cos(PI/2);
    x2 = y2*cos(SOME_CONSTANT);
    ...
    outputValues(x1, x2, ...);
}
```

the obvious optimization would be to compute the cosines ahead-of-time. I could do this by filling an array with the values but I was wondering would it be possible to make the compiler compute these at compile-time?

Edit: I know that C doesn't have compile-time evaluation but I was hoping there would had been some weird and ugly way to do this with macros.

Comment: Actually the whole y1 business should be optimized out (by yourself) since cos(PI/2) = 0...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're lucky, you won't have to do anything: Modern compilers do constant propagation for functions in the same translation unit and intrinsic functions (which most likely will include the math functions).

Look at the assembly to check if that's the case for your compiler and increase the optimization levels if necessary.

Comment: I'd be surprised if constant propagation included calling libraries only present in the link stage? Or am i missing something?

Comment: GCC has support for this since 4.3. See the release notes : http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html

Comment: @Oli, Mitch: clarified my answer

Answer (score 1):

Nope. A pre-computed lookup table would be the only way. In fact, `Cosine` (and `Sine`) might even be implemented that way in your libraries.

Profile first, Optimise Later.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately.

I would recommend writing a little program (or script) that generates a list of these values (which you can then `#include` into the correct place), that is run as part of your build process.

**By the way:** cos(pi/2) = 0!

Answer (score 1):

You assume that computing `cos` is more expensive than an access. Perhaps this is not true on your architecture. Thus you should do some testing (profiling) - as always with optimization ideas.

Comment: Without hacks like `-ffast-math` which are nonconformant, it's pretty much impossible for `cos()` to be faster than an access due to corner case support and `errno`/floating point exceptions support. Of course maybe the compiler could determine that these are not needed due to the bounds on your arguments and use an inline fpu opcode.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of precomputing these values, it is possible to use global variables to hold the values, which would be computed once on program startup.

Comment: they don't have to be globals, just constants.

Answer (score 0):

No, C doesn't have the concept of compile time evaluation of functions and not even of symbolic constants if they are of type double. The only way to have them as immediate operand would be to precompute them and then to define them in macros. This is the way the C library does it for pi for example.

Comment: this is not a feature of the language, but the implementation; also, newer versions of gcc as well as clang will do such optimizations

Comment: @Christoph: your sure about compile time expansion of trigonometric functions? In any case, my argument remains that there are no symbolic constants in C of type `double`. If you'd have them as precomputed values, you should use macros to refer to them. This is guaranteed to give the best result on whatever architecture.

Comment: yes, I'm sure of compile-time evaluation of trigonometric functions in gcc and clang - try it yourself; also, I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say there are no 'symbolic constants' of type `double`: arithmetic constant expressions may well have floating-point type; however, enumerations, `case` labels and preprocessor-conditionals only accept integer constant expressions; is that what you meant?

Comment: @Christoph: Ok, great, wouldn't have thought that they are capable of that. For your question, yes, in a similar case with `int` values you could use `enum` constants to have a named compile time constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code and the compiler is not hoisting the constant values out of the loop, then do so yourself.

If the arguments to the trig functions are constant as in your sample code, then either pre-compute them yourself, or make them static variables so they are only computed once. If they vary between calls, but are constant within the loop then move them to outside the loop. If they vary between iterations of the loop, then a look-up table may be faster, but if that is acceptable accuracy then implementing your own trig functions which halt the calculation at a lower accuracy is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

I am struck with awe by [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48015/christoph)'s answer above.

So nothing needs to be done in this case, where gcc has some knowledge about the math functions. But if you have a function (maybe implemented by you) which cannot be calculated by your C compiler or if your C compiler is not so clever (or you need to fill complicated data structures or some other reason) you can use some higher level language to act as macroprocessor. In the past, I have used [eRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby) for this purpose, but ([ePerl](http://man.cx/eperl(1)) should work very well too and is another obvious readily available and more or less comfortable choice.

You can specify make rules for transforming files with extension `.eruby` (or `.eperl`  or whatever) to files with that extension stripped out so that, for example, if you write files `module.c.eruby` or `module.h.eruby` then `make` automatically knows how to generate `module.c` or `module.h`, respectively, and keeps them up-to-date. In your make rule you can easily add generation of comment that warns editing the file directly.

If you are using Windows or something similar, then I am out of my depths in explaining how to add support for running this transformation automatically for you by your favorite IDE. But I believe it should be possible, or you could just run `make` outside of your IDE whenever you need to change those `.eruby` (or whatever) files.

By the way, I have seen that with incredibly small lines of code I have seen eLua implemented to use [Lua](http://www.lua.org) as a macro language. Of course any other scripting language with support for regular expressions and flexible layout rules should work as well (but [Python](http://www.python.org) is malsuited for this purpose due to strict white space rules).